# Git pushes new branch with master content

Tags: git, mercurial

I migrate a repo from mercurial to git through:

```
git init gitrepo
cd gitrepo
hg_fastexport -r <../hgclone>
```

(I hope I didn´t forget anything) Then I created in GitLab an repository and in the gitrepo (to where hg-fastexport exported the sources) I created branches and pushed them like

```
git checkout -b v4.1
git push origin refs/heads/v4.1:refs/heads/v4.1
```

While this was working with 2 branches, it showed also up in Gitab, the last branch always gets the content of the master branch, not the v4.1 branch.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error i´ve made. Maybe the problem was not so clear, but when i created a new branch the branch would had always the content of the master. It would contain not the branch. The reason for that was that i´ve forget, after i migrated from mercury to git, to check out the HEAD. It seems as if then i was working either on the master or a branch but while i forgot to checkout the (newly migrated HEAD), the content of the new branch and the master remained the same.

I will give here a receipt which led to a correct repository.

clone the Mercurial directory:

- **hg clone http:mercurial.com ./hgclone**

Init the git directory:

- **git init git-dir**
- **cd git-dir**
- migrate mercurial to git: **hg-fast-export -r ../hgclone**
- **git checkout HEAD**
- Add git repository: **git remote add origin *$remoterepo***
- Add current dir: **git add .**
- commit: **git commit -m "Initial Commit"**
- push: **git push -u origin master**

List the branches for to create and update them to the remote git-directory
  - **git branch**

checkout and add the branches to the remote git directory:

- **git checkout *branch***
- **git add .**
- **git push origin refs/heads/*branch*:refs/heads/*branch***

This are the fundamental steps which worked for me for exporting a mercurial repository to git and store them with the right branches to the remote git repository.

Answer (score 1):

[It's still not clear what your actual question is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546770/git-pushes-new-branch-with-master-content#comment84090673_48546770), so I'll make one up for you:

#### How can Git have the same commit in two different branches? (Mercurial can't.)

The reason for this is is that in Mercurial, a commit has no independent existence from its branch, and a branch consists entirely of its commits.  That is, each commit belongs to *precisely one branch*.  A branch *name* is an entity that means "every commit whose recorded branch is this entity."

In Git, by contrast, commits are *independent of branches*.  A commit exists, or does not exist, only because it exists, or does not exist.  A commit does not record which branches, if any, contain it.  A branch *name* is just an alias for one (1) hash ID, and *which* hash ID it is an alias for can be changed, at any time.

In both VCSes, every commit records its parent commit ID(s): one ID if the commit is an ordinary, non-merge commit, and at least two—two or more in Git, exactly two in Mercurial—if the commit is a merge commit.  This means that in either VCS, if we are given some particular commit, we can inspect that commit and find its parent or (if a merge) parents.  We can then inspect the parent(s) and find their parent(s), and so on.

If we do this for all of what Mercurial calls *heads*, we find all commits in the Mercurial repository.  The commits act as vertices (or nodes) in a directed, acyclic graph or DAG; the arcs connecting these nodes are the parent IDs.  Every commit we find this way is on exactly one branch, and each commit records which (single) branch it's on.

In Git, by contrast, we don't really know *where* to start.  We can exhaustively enumerate the entire repository to find all objects (Git has four *types* of objects in its repository database), pick out all the commit objects, and form the DAG from here.  These commits, though, have *no* branch identification: we don't know which branch the commits are on!  Moreover, this exhaustive enumeration takes a long time—minutes, even, in a large repository—so we hardly ever bother.

Instead, we take a completely different approach: we start with the hash ID stored in one branch name, such as `master`.  Using that one branch name, we find one commit.  That commit, by definition, is on `master`.  Then we find that commit's parent(s), using the hash ID(s) stored in that commit.  Those commits, by definition, are also on `master`.  We repeat this process until, having followed all reachable parent arcs through the DAG, we have identified every commit that is reachable from the name `master`, and *all of these commits are on `master`.*

But there are probably more branch names.  So we start from another name, such as `v4.1`.  This name contains a hash ID, which locates a commit.  That commit, by definition, is on `v4.1`.  We then find that commit's parent(s), just as before.  Those commits, by definition, are also on `v4.1`.  We repeat this process until, having followed all reachable parent arcs through the DAG, we have identified every commit that is reachable from the name `v4.1`, and *all of these commits are on `v4.1`.*

Note that in most commit DAGs, there's generally one initial commit from which all other commits are descended.  In Mercurial, this one commit is on *one* branch, probably the one named `default`.  In Git, this one commit is *on every branch*.

Thus, **the fundamental difference between a Git commit and a Mercurial commit is that a Git commit is on many branches simultaneously.**  The set of branches that contain any given Git commit is determined dynamically, by consulting *all* branches and following *all* of them through the DAG until we see that this particular commit either is, or is not, *reachable from* the one specific commit at the tip of the branch.  If it is reachable this way, it is on that branch; if not, it is not.

#### The consequence of this is that branch creation is different

In both Git and Mercurial, to create a new branch, you tell the VCS "create a new branch"—but the *immediate action* is very different, *except* in a new, empty repository.<sup>1</sup>

In Git, for a *branch name* to exist, the *name* must identify *one particular commit*.  Git calls this the *tip* of the branch, and we say that the branch name *points to* that particular commit.  But in a new, empty repository, *there are no commits*, so no branch names can exist!

Mercurial has a similar problem: a branch consists of all the commits that are in that branch.  In a new empty repository, there are no commits, so no branches exist!

Nonetheless, both Git and Mercurial have the notion of a *current* branch.  The current branch is the branch on which *new* commits will be made.  This allows both VCSes to record the current branch *name* as a branch that does not actually *exist* yet.  Once you have done this, creating a new commit has the side effect of creating the branch.  Both VCSes do this for a new, totally-empty repository: the first commit *creates* the current branch (usually `default` and `master`).

In Mercurial, this is all very simple and automatic: you create a new commit; its branch is whatever the recorded "current branch" is; if that's the first time a commit has been created on branch `xyzzy`, well, now there is at least one commit on `xyzzy`, so `xyzzy` exists.

But when Git creates a new branch `xyzzy` and there *are* some existing commits and branches, Git simply creates `xyzzy` immediately, pointing to the current commit.  Let's say you were on `master` before, and have just created `xyzzy`.  The names `xyzzy` and `master` now point to the *same* commit: now all the commits that were on `master` before are on *both* `master` *and* `xyzzy`.

**In short, this is entirely normal in Git.**  Creating a new commit while on branch `v1.4` will make that new commit be *only* on branch `v1.4`, at least until something else happens to make some other branch contain that commit as well.  Creating a new commit, while on a branch, tells Git to *set* that branch tip to point to the newly-created commit.  The parent ID of the newly-created commit will be the previous tip (since that is what you had checked-out), so the branch now contains every commit it contained before, plus the new one just made.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can make Git act a bit more like Mercurial using `git checkout --orphan`, but if you do this, the *next* commit you make will create a new *root* commit—a new commit with no parents, creating a separate sub-graph within the commit DAG.  This is almost never what you want: in Git, you *want* commits to be on multiple branches simultaneously.  The one time you *always* want this "orphan branch" behavior is in a new, empty repository, to create the very first commit.

Comment: Thank you Torek for your answer, i solved my special problem, it had an other reason and will add it to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b v4.1
```

The `-b` tells git to **create** a new branch, from whatever branch you are at the time (probably `master`), and then switch to it, which means that branch `v4.1` will point to the exact same commit as the source branch does (again, probably `master`)...

It seems **you forgot to commit your changes before pushing**.

The branch `v4.1` will only have the changes you've made after you commit them.

Comment: Hello, i´ve already checkouted with the -b option. The problem is that, in this case, it still has the same content as master, nothing changed. (As mentioned, the other occasions it checkout properly. (commit doesn´t change anything in this case, it still has the same content as master).